# Site analytics show no votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, site-analytics

I very recently had an interest to check the voting behaviour on math.se and the `/site-analytics` page isn't showing any votes cast.

[image: no votes ever on math.se]

I also checked the moderator `/admin/analytics` page and still, no votes cast.

Something is borked on those pages.

---

I have been told that at least one other site is also experiencing this problem, so I don't think it is site-specific.

Comment: No repro on MSE ...

Comment: Can repro on Math.SE, investigating.

Comment: Happens for Posts too if you select Private beta as the start.

Comment: Repro on Puzzling SE.

Comment: @MichaelStum Reproduced on EL&U. Still happening.

Comment: @MattEllen Can you retry once more?

Comment: @MichaelStum Both pages are working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so the TL;DR is that we were fetching good data, and then accidentally zeroed them out when delivering to the client (Basically we were comparing a .net `DateTime` with a Time portion to a `DateTime` without a time portion). That affects other parts of the report as well.

This is now fixed, although data is cached for an hour and thus will stay 0 until about an hour from when this answer was written.

Thanks for the report and sorry for the inconvenience!